# Approximation of π by computing the sum of the first few terms

Tags: python, pi

The constant π is an irrational number with value approximately 3.1415928 . . . The precise value of π is equal to this infinite sum:π=4/1−4/3+4/5−4/7+4/9−4/11+ ...We can get a good approximation of π by computing the sum of the first few terms. Write a function approxPi() that takes as input a float-value error and approximates constant π within error by computing the preceding sum, term by term, until the difference between the current sum and the previous sum (with one less term) is no greater than error. The function should return the new sum.(hints:  π1=4/1;  π3=4-4/3;  π5=4-4/3+4/5; ... πi= πi-2+sign*4/i  where sign=-1 or 1)
approxPi(0.01) 3.1465677471829556 
approxPi(0.0000001) 3.1415927035898146 
the code I have is

```
def approxPi(num): 
prev=1
current=2
i=1
while current-prev>num:
    prev=current
    current+= 4-(4/i)
    i += 1
return current
```

this just gives me 2 though, any suggestions would help.

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables because your calculation are not correct. In every step you add 4 and substract 4/1, 4/2, 4/3, 4/5. If you print `i` inside loop you will see it run loop only once.

Comment: "We can get a good approximation of π by computing the sum of the first few terms" - not really, because this series converges painfully slowly. It's a really bad series to choose for actually computing pi.

Comment: If you think carefully about your loop calculation, you'll find it doesn't match the formula at all. Take a paper and pen/pencil and manually go through it a couple of times.

Comment: you should calculate `current += sign * (4/i)` and change `sign = -sign` and use `i += 2`, not `i += 1`. And you will have to compare absolute value for `abs(current - prev) > num`. With these changes I get correct result.

Answer (score 0):

A corrected version of your code is as follows

```
def approxPi(num): 
prev=1
current=2
i=1
sign = 1;
while abs(current-prev)>num:
    prev=current
    current+= sign * (4/i)
    sign = -sign
    i += 2
current -= 2
return current
```

The denominator of every fraction of the series is 2 plus the previous one, hence `i += 2`. The `sign = -sign` is used to alternate between positive and negative signs in your series. The `current -= 2` is to substract 2 from the series since `current = 2` is the first value of the series. Finally, the `abs()` is needed to get the absolute value of the error, since it can alternate between positive and negative error values.

Comment: This is making is off by 2, so I subtracted 2 and the program won't load in the answers.

Comment: @tynastyyy What do you mean by *off by 2*?

Comment: @tynastyyy Also what means *won't load the answers*. In any case I edited the answer, it includes an extra line to get rid of initial 2 in the series.

Comment: @tynastyyy Also what means *won't load the answers*. In any case I edited the answer, it includes an extra line to get rid of initial 2 in the series. Also, it's important for you to know that in Python **indentation matters**. Be careful, cause a misplaced space or tab can significantly alter your program.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is more idiomatic python and easier to understand.

```
def approxPI(n):
   cal1 = [1.0/float(i) for i in range(1, n, 4)]
   cal2 = [1.0/float(i) for i in range(3, n, 4)]
   pi = (sum(cal1)-sum(cal2)) * 4
   return pi
print(approxPI(400000))
```

It is pretty fast, calculating 400,000th series in 0.05s on a desktop PC.